# LeetCode 76: Minimum Window Substring - Java

Tags: java, performance, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge

I'm posting my Java code for the [Minimum Window Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/). If you have time and would like to review, please do so, I appreciate that.

#### Problem

> Given a string `string` and a string `target`, find the minimum window
> in `string` which will contain all the characters in `target` in
> complexity O(n).
>
> Example:
>
> Input: `string` = "ADOBECODEBANC", `target` = "ABC" Output: "BANC"
> Note:
>
> If there is no such window in `string` that covers all characters in
> `target`, return the empty string "". If there is such window, you are
> guaranteed that there will always be only one unique minimum window in
> `string`.

#### Java

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.util.*;

class Solution {
    public String minWindow(String string, String target) {
        if (string == null || target == null || string.length() == 0 || target.length() == 0 || string.length() < target.length()) {
            return "";
        }

        int minLeft = 0, minRight = 0, min = string.length();
        boolean flag = false;
        int targetLength = target.length();
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(targetLength);
        

        for (char character : target.toCharArray()) {
            map.put(character, -~map.getOrDefault(character, 0));
        }

        int left = 0, right = 0;

        while (right < string.length()) {
            char character = string.charAt(right);
            map.put(character, map.getOrDefault(character, 0) - 1);

            if (map.get(character) > -1) {
                targetLength--;
            }


            while (targetLength == 0 && left <= right) {
                flag = true;
                int curLength = -~right - left;

                if (curLength <= min) {
                    minLeft = left;
                    minRight = right;
                    min = curLength;
                }

                char leftChar = string.charAt(left);
                map.put(leftChar, -~map.getOrDefault(leftChar, 0));

                if (map.get(leftChar) > 0) {
                    targetLength++;
                }

                left++;
            }

            right++;
        }

        return flag == true ? string.substring(minLeft, -~minRight) : "";
    }
}
```

#### Reference

- [Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/solution/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/solution/)
- [Discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some suggestions.

### Extract some of the logic to methods.

In your code, I see at least three sections of code that could be in methods. In my opinion, those extraction will help with the reading and make the code a bit shorter.

1. The validation of the parameters.

**Before**

```java
if (string == null || target == null || string.length() == 0 || target.length() == 0 || string.length() < target.length()) {
   return "";
}
```

**After**

```java
public String minWindow(String string, String target) {
   //[...]
   if (haveInvalidParameters(string, target)) {
      return "";
   }
   //[...]
}

private boolean haveInvalidParameters(String string, String target) {
   return string == null || target == null || string.length() == 0 || target.length() == 0 || string.length() < target.length();
}
```

2. The map initialization.

**Before**

```java
//[...]
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(targetLength);
for (char character : target.toCharArray()) {
   map.put(character, -~map.getOrDefault(character, 0));
}
//[...]
```

**After**

```java
public String minWindow(String string, String target) {
   //[...]
   Map<Character, Integer> map = initializeMap(target, targetLength);
   //[...]
}

private Map<Character, Integer> initializeMap(String target, int targetLength) {
   Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(targetLength);
   for (char character : target.toCharArray()) {
      map.put(character, -~map.getOrDefault(character, 0));
   }
   return map;
}
```

3. The substring section.

**Before**

```java
public String minWindow(String string, String target) {
   //[...]
   return flag == true ? string.substring(minLeft, -~minRight) : "";
}
```

**After**

```java
public String minWindow(String string, String target) {
   //[...]
   return applySubstring(string, minLeft, minRight, flag);
}

private String applySubstring(String string, int minLeft, int minRight, boolean flag) {
   return flag == true ? string.substring(minLeft, -~minRight) : "";
}
```

### Try to keep the variable declarations at the top of the blocks.

Generally in Java, we try to put the variable declarations at the top of the blocks.

- [Code Conventions for the Java (Revised April 20, 1999)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#16817)

**Before**

```java
int left = 0, right = 0;
```

**After**

```java
int minLeft = 0, minRight = 0, min = string.length();
int left = 0, right = 0;
```

### You can simplify the boolean expression

```java
return flag == true ? string.substring(minLeft, -~minRight) : "";
```

**is equals to**

```java
return flag ? string.substring(minLeft, -~minRight) : "";
```